# Accessing files on Linux container from host sans root

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server, arch-linux

I have a container from systemd-nspawn. The folder for the container `/var/lib/machines/our-runner` is owned by `vu-our-runner-0:vg-our-runner-0`. I am trying to serve files within it from the hosts apache2 instance, however, I cannot do `usermod -aG vg-our-runner-0 www-data`, as it says that `vg-our-runner-0` does not exist, despite `ls -ld` saying otherwise. How would I give apache access to this short of running it as root (as root has access to the folders within the container)? The host is Debian, the container is Arch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it says that vg-our-runner-0 does not exist, despite ls -ld saying otherwise

Well, those aren't the same thing. It is true that the group doesn't "exist" in /etc/group where usermod looks – it's a virtual group defined by systemd-machined. It is *also* true that the group "exists" when the getgrnam() or getgrid() functions are called by ls – because they collect information from *more* places than just /etc/group.

The /etc/passwd and /etc/group files are not only source of passwd & group information on Linux. When a program like `ls -l` tries to look up a group name or GID, multiple *nsswitch modules* can supply this information. (They're all listed in /etc/nsswitch.conf, and the 'libnss_files' module is what actually reads /etc/group.)

In particular, `ls -l` also asks the 'libnss_mymachines' module which is installed by systemd and provides information *on the fly* about currently running containers. It's also why the group suddenly stops being recognized when the container is stopped. (It's also why all vu-/vg- names stop being recognized whenever systemd-machined exits on idle...)

Fortunately, nsswitch has a special case for groups where it supports merging membership results from several modules; if you *manually* add this group to /etc/group, making sure to preserve its GID, then you will be able to add members to it.

So you could look up the GID using `ls -ldn` (e.g. 1164378112 in this case) and add a new line to /etc/group like this:

```
echo "vg-our-runner-0:x:1164378112:www-data" >> /etc/group
```

Now tools like `id www-data` or `groups www-data` (which collect group memberships through nsswitch) will report the new GID. It doesn't matter to the kernel where the group was defined – a GID is a GID.

Comment: ThanksI I've been able to add my own account and www-data to the group with your answer, however, I still cannot access its directory. Running `namei -l /var/lib/machines/our-runner/` results [in the following.](https://gist.github.com/Orangian/f33e8efcdce71c9d379920052c08fb9d) So it seems like even though I am part of the vg-our-runner-0 group, I still strangely do not have access.

Comment: It also seems like both vu-our-runner-0 and vg-our-runner-0 have the same id of 73007104. Trying su vu-our-runner-0 as root also gives me an authentication error strangely enough.

Comment: You're not allowed to descend into the /var/lib/machines directory because you don't have the `x` permission on it. At this point, deeper permissions aren't even checked yet.

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for your help! I'm kinda new to unix, so I don't have a clue what most attributes do. Resolved.